# javascript array shift function does not working in canvas

Tags: javascript

Something is wrong with my canvas coding. It is not working properly. The `shift()` works only once. It should make the drawing disappear, but it is working normal purpose. Did I do something wrong?

```
<canvas id='ctx' width="500px" height="500px" style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
//object array
car_asd=[
  {x:100,y:100},
  {x:105,y:100},
  {x:110,y:100}
];
// end of object array
var ctx=document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d"); 
function a() {
  car_asd.shift();//does not working all time
  for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    cars=car_asd[i];
    ctx.fillRect(cars.x,cars.y,10,10);
  }
}
setInterval(function(){ a() }, 10);
</script>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the shift(), the problem is that the drawings from previous calls to a() is still showing.

So, you need to clear the canvas at the beginning of the function a():

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
```